# How do I uniquely identify a docker image that is imported from tar file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am exporting a set of docker images to a tar file so that I can load them onto a machine that is unable to connect directly to my private docker registry.  I am using docker-compose to connect the running containers together.  To ensure that I always use an exact version of the image that these containers are created from, I **had** been using the sha256 digest of the container instead of a specific tag to uniquely identify the image.

In other words, in my docker-compose file, instead of using a tag to identify the image:

```
image: registry/image:19.1.3
```

I'm using the sha256 digest:

```
image: registry/image@sha256:<digest>
```

However, when I import a docker image from a tar file, the digest is not brought along with it.  This prevents me from running the image by using the digest.  What other unique identifying item can I use (not just `image:tag`) to uniquely identify this specific instance of an image?  Is the docker image ID sufficient to fulfill this purpose?

Answer (score -1):

First of all containers don't have versions. Images do. And if you use repository/image:tag you are good to go. You can save that and load it in a new machine. I have seen people do it pleanty so I guarantee it works.

You can inspect an image to see its layers:

```
docker inspect <image>
```

You can compare this before save and after load and you should get the same result.

If it still doesn't work for you maybe post the full docker-compose you are using as well as other commands. Maybe the error is there.